# VB.net - How can i sort data in a 2dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I am facing (for me) a bit of a challenge. I have created for Autodesk Inventor a BOM export tool using it's API. This kinda works except for the fact that the exported order is scrambled. I've been given the advice from Autodesk to use a workaround because the API does not allow me to export the BOM in right order.

After some comments on this topic I realized my question was entirely wrong, so i edited the question

1) What I would like to do is create a Array of my BOM 2) sort it and then 3) export into a different program (Excel in my case).

1) Create a Array for the BOM

```
    Private Sub QueryBOMRowProperties(oBOMRows As BOMRowsEnumerator, ItemTab As Long)
    ItemTab = ItemTab + 3
    ' Iterate through the contents of the BOM Rows.
    Dim i As Long
    Dim oCompDef As Inventor.ComponentDefinition
    Dim oItemNumber As String
    Dim oDescription As Inventor.Property
    Dim oQTY As Integer
    Dim oMaterial As String

    For i = 1 To oBOMRows.Count

        ' Get the current row.
        Dim oRow As BOMRow
        oRow = oBOMRows.Item(i)

        oCompDef = oRow.ComponentDefinitions.Item(1)

        oItemNumber = oRow.ItemNumber
        oDescription = oCompDef.Document.PropertySets.Item("Design Tracking Properties").Item("Description")
        oQTY = oRow.ItemQuantity

        If TypeOf oCompDef Is PartComponentDefinition Then

            Dim oPartCompDef As PartComponentDefinition
            oPartCompDef = oCompDef
            oMaterial = oPartCompDef.Material.Name
        Else
            oMaterial = ""

        End If

        ReDim Preserve oBOMArray(3, i)
        oBOMArray(0, i) = oItemNumber
        oBOMArray(1, i) = oDescription.Value
        oBOMArray(2, i) = oQTY
        oBOMArray(3, i) = oMaterial

        Debug.Print(oBOMArray(0, i) & " | " & oBOMArray(1, i) & " | " & oBOMArray(2, i) & " | " & oBOMArray(3, i))

        'Recursively iterate child rows if present.
        If Not oRow.ChildRows Is Nothing Then
            Call QueryBOMRowProperties(oRow.ChildRows, ItemTab)
        End If

    Next
    ItemTab = ItemTab - 3

End Sub
```

This gives me this result, as you can see the itemnumbers are not sorted nicely.

```
1 | Pipe ø88,9 x 6,3 - lg. 427mm | 1 | WN 1.4306
3 | Elbow 90deg DN80(ø88,9) x 3,2 - acc. DIN 2605 type 3 | 1 | WN 1.4306
4 | Pipe ø88,9 x 3,2 - lg. 161mm | 1 | WN 1.4306
2 | Repad ø200 x 12mm (Plate 201 x 200) | 1 | WN 1.4307
6 | Hex Head Plug 1/4in - acc. ASME B16.11 | 1 | A2
5 | Plate ø110 x 5mm | 1 | WN 1.4307
7 |    "C-BW-2" : Buttweld nozzle | 1 | 
7.2 | Pipe ø88,9 x 6,3 - lg. 427mm | 1 | WN 1.4306
7.3 | Elbow 90deg DN80(ø88,9) x 3,2 - acc. DIN 2605 type 3 | 1 | WN 1.4306
7.4 | Repad ø200 x 12mm (Plate 201 x 200) | 1 | WN 1.4307
7.5 | Hex Head Plug 1/4in - acc. ASME B16.11 | 1 | A2
7.1 | Plate ø110 x 5mm | 1 | WN 1.4307
```

2) Sort the Itemnumbers

You could say use the `IndexOf` to find the row you want to export, but this would force me to know exactly which itemnumbers are in the array (at least I think)

I would think that my best chance is to sort the item numbers into the correct order but can someone point me into the right direction to do this? Especially how do you do this with the subnumbers in the array?

Or should I look at `SortedList` ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

3) Export the item, is just writing them out to Excel and clearing the array when done.

Comment: The displayed data doesn't represent a 2D array. Please, show the code where this array is being created/populated such that we can understand the situation properly. Additionally, bear in mind that you are expected to do some effort by your own before asking here (= include also your sorting attempts).

Comment: You could create two 1D arrays from the "columns" of data and then use the overload of `Array.Sort` that allows you to sort two arrays using one as keys for the other.  You can then write the sorted data back into the 2D array.

Comment: @varocarbas I added my array creation code. How does my array not represent a 2D array? does it not have a X-Y axis?

Comment: A 2D array is not a set of couple values (x & y or whatever), this is a 1D array (both values per dimension via string array or a dictionary or a class with two properties, etc.). A 2D array (understood in its widest sense of .NET collection) responds to the idea of as many sets of values in the second dimension as first dimensions. Examples: 1 - 1, 2 - 2, etc. is 1-D. 1 - (1,2,3), 2 - (5,6,7), etc. is 2D. You are proving it in your sample code: your (formally) 2D array behaves in a 1D day as far as you are only really affecting the second dimension (`i`).

Comment: The 2D essence in your code is completely unnecessary (you are wasting memory resources for no reason). If you are always adding a single value to the second dimension why using it at all? (its whole point is including more than one value). You can replace your 2D array with a 1D one of the form `1DArray(i) = oRow.ItemNumber` and sort it on account of its values (via `OrderBy`, for example).

Comment: Okay, i think i get what you are saying. But how will i know after i have sorted it what the corresponding row number was for the ItemNumber?

ie rownumber 4 belongs to itemnumber 2. If you put the itemnumbers in a 1D array it will put the itemnumber on position 4, but will you be able to trace it's original position after sorting it? Or am I really looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: 1D arrays are defined by index and value; that is: `array(index) = associated_value`. In your example, `array(rownumber) = itemnumber` -> `array(4) = 2`. To know the `itemnumber` in the `rownumber = 4`, you can do `myvalue = array(4)` (= 2). To know the `rownumber` associated with `itemnumber = 2`, you can use different alternatives (like `IndexOf`). You have many options (in .NET there are many different collections which can be configured in many different ways). In any case, all this is basic 1D/2D collections understanding what is off-topic here, better do some tests/learning by your own.

Comment: I updated my question. Based on @varocarbas your comments I realized that it's wrong of me too even look at the Row-ID. I think it's best that i fully load the data I want to export into my Array, sort it and then export it? So I think my question title is now more accurate as the Array is two dimensional?

Comment: You cannot keep redefining the question; this is not how SO works. Additionally, this is still off-topic: there are many different ways to account for what you want. I personally would rely on a custom class and create a simple collection for it (an array or a list depending upon the exact conditions). For example: `Class Elements`... with the properties `description As String`, `itemNo As Integer`, etc. and `listAllItems As List(Of Elements)`. Then you can use LINQ (e.g., `OrderBy`) to sort this list at will. This is the last time I am helping here, please use SO as intended.